# What is exactly in my crypto wallet and how does pass phrases work?

Tags: wallets, passphrase

I know my crypto wallet does not contain my actual coins but a private key. Is this all that is contained in a wallet? if so how is it possible to restore a wallet on another computer by just knowing the pass phrases?

Comment: Read MyCrypto's article [How do Secret Recovery Phrases Work?](https://support.mycrypto.com/general-knowledge/cryptography/how-do-mnemonic-phrases-work)

Comment: Did not get an answer in the post you link. I am wondering how is it possible to use recovery phase to get back a private key?

Comment: That post answers all the questions that you asked originally. How to get the private key of the first wallet generated with a mnemonic is a different question.

Comment: Install [MyCrypto](https://mycrypto.com), then load your pass phrase, then find the "Wallet Info" option in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it as a mathematical equation of a curve with two value X and Y to represent a point on that curve.

Now crypto keys work the same way.

X is your public key (address)
Y is your private key (secret)

All the funds of this wallet are written on the blockchain.
To spend them you have to resolve the curve by providing Y to the algorithm as a proof of ownership.

This is basically how it works!

the 12 words seed phrase are just a convenient way of representing bytes so you can write them down but they are bytes.

Comment: > the 12 words seed phrase are just a convenient way of representing bytes so you can write them down but they are bytes.

this is the part I am curious about. Do you know exactly how the 12 words seed phrase are used to represent bytes?

Comment: Well they use dictionary and match the words to the bytes. Or find a matching word that match the bytes. The characters on your screen are bytes. So you can take some bytes and turn them into words. You should create a wallet and study the process.